# Get Filname without extension from string with regex

Tags: java, regex, filenames, extract

I have a string that contains a URL to a file. From that string I like to get just the filename without extension.

For example:

```
http://path/Lists/Test/Attachments/1/Document Test.docx
```

From that example I like to get back: `Document Test`

I already have the following pattern:

```
(?<=\/)(\w+)(?=\.\w+(\?.*)*$)
```

But it does not work if the filename contains spaces... How can I change this pattern that it is more flexible?

Comment: Have a look at `substring` and `lastIndexOf` in the String class

Comment: Which language are you using? There're loads of faster and more efficient options depending on your language of choice.

Comment: `java` class library may have an alternative to regex!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To capture just the characters before the extension (without limiting what characters a file name may contain) use the following:

```
/[^/]*(?=\.[^.]+($|\?))/
```

Comment: Many thanks, this works great for me. But I am now at this point that I need the filename + extension. So I am using now the following pattern to remove everything that is before the filename.ext: `.*/`

Comment: That second backslash causes problems in PHP. I had to escape it, so: `/[^\/]*(?=\.[^.]+($|\?))/`

Answer (score 4):

Don't use regex when you don't have to. In this case substring between `lastIndexOF` `/` and `.` would give you what you want.

```
String data = "Document Testdocx";

int start = data.lastIndexOf('/')+1;
int end = data.lastIndexOf('.');
if (end == -1) end = data.length();

System.out.println(data.substring(start , end));
```

But if you really must use regex you can try this pattern: `(?<=/|^)[^./]+(?=\\.\\w+$|$)`

Comment: Really? And which one is more efficient?

Comment: @Kata In most cases regex is slower then simple solutions.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
    String s = "http://path/Lists/Test/Attachments/1/Document Test.docx";
    s = s.replaceAll(".+/(.+)\\..+", "$1");
    System.out.println(s);
```

output

```
Document Test
```

Answer (score 2):

```
([^?]+)\/([^/?]+)(\.[^.\?]+)(\?.*|)$
```

Even if the URL looks like

```
http://example.com/foo/bar/baz blah.html?params=true
```

this can find the file name (without the directory) and the extension.

Probably better would be to parse the URL with [java.net.URL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html), and use URL.getPath().

Comment: +1 for mentioning java.net.URL class.. Your answer will improve further if you include an example of that.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `(?<=/)(\w+)(?=.\w+(\?.)$)`, try `(.+?)(\.[^.]*$|$)`